# append element in head of an iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to append a style sheet(css) link to the head of an iframe using jquery .
i tried with the following code but not working.

```
$('#tabsFrame').contents().find("head").append(cssLink);
```

Comment: looks good, can you provide the HTML aswell ? And how exactly is `cssLink` defined ?

Comment: var cssLink = $('<link href="cupertino_1.4/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" class="ui-theme" />');

Comment: ok fine. what is the `<iframe>`'s `src` attribute?

Comment: <iframe frameborder="0" id="tabsFrame" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" src="tabs.jsp"></iframe>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i am used to append data to an iframe by using this line of code

`$('body', window.frames[target].document).append(data);`

In your case, this line would look like this

`$('head', window.frames['tabsFrame'].document).append(cssLink);`

EDIT:

Add `<head></head>` to the iframe and change your var cssLink to

`cssLink = '<link href="cupertino_1.4/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" class="ui-theme" />`

Comment: i tried tour suggestion but the CSS file gets downloaded in the browser as a text file

Comment: Just saw your comments in the question. HAve you added `<head></head>` to the iframe?

Comment: Do you have any debugger like Firebug etc? Does it give you any clue on what is happening upon adding the cssLink to the iframe?

Answer (score 3):

well, you can check with this:

```
$('#tabsFrame').contents().find("head")[0].appendChild(cssLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't manipulate the content of an iframe because of security.
Having you be able to do such a thing would make cross-site-scripting too easy.

The iframe is totally seperate from the DOM of your page.

Also, java and javascript are two completely different things!

Follow the Link to see the difference [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml)

Comment: That is only true, if the `document.domain` from the iframe does **not** equal the domain from the parent window.

Answer (score -1):

This could be related to IE not allowing you to add elements in the DOM, check out the clever solution [here](http://scriptble.com/2011/02/16/writing-and-updating-dom-elements-in-a-frame/)

**EDIT:**

Thanks @kris, good advice to add more info in case links break:

Here is the main code snippet from the link, in case it goes out again.
(This is only needed with some IE version, for the most part, the other answer work just fine)

```
var ifrm;

//attempts to retrieve the IFrame document    
function addElementToFrame(newStyle) {
    if (typeof ifrm == "undefined") {
        ifrm = document.getElementById('previewFrame');
        if (ifrm.contentWindow) {
            ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow;
        } else {
            if (ifrm.contentDocument.document) {
                ifrm = ifrm.contentDocument.document;
            } else {
                ifrm = ifrm.contentDocument;
            }
        }
    }

    //Now that we have the document, look for an existing style tag
    var tag = ifrm.document.getElementById("tempTag");

    //if you need to replace the existing tag, we first need to remove it
    if (typeof tag != "undefined" || tag != null) {
        $("#tempTag", ifrm.document).remove();
    }

    //add a new style tag
    $("HEAD", ifrm.document).append("");
}
```

Comment: The link went dead. That is why one always should include a summary of linked content.

Comment: @kris thanks man, good advice. Luckily the link just changed, but just in case I added the relevant code.