# Append a whole page to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append a whole page (with `<html><head>` and `<body>` elements) inside an existent empty iframe.

Is it possible at all?

As far as I've seen they always append the content to some child element in the iframe, such as `body`:

```
$('#demo').contents().find('body').html('aaa');
```

But I'm trying the append a whole page, with styles, head and so on, so I would need to append it to the document level.
Something like this:

```
//not working
$('#demo').contents().html('<html><body>aaaa</body></html>');
```

Comment: What's the problem setting iframe `src`? If you want to access cross domain iframe if no cross origin access enabled, you'd have anyway to proxify it server side so not sure what is your issue here. But is it for same domain page?

Comment: I'm getting the content from a web service. It is not an actual html file, but a string containing the whole generated page.

Comment: Maybe its not possible to do both `head` and `body`. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990165/append-element-in-head-of-an-iframe-using-jquery) they are suggesting head and body seperately

Comment: @Alvaro But how looks like the string from webservice, is that like a HTML source page?

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah. A "whole" page. It is a standalone page itself. With its `<head>`, its own `<style>` tags...

Comment: Append it to contentDocument.documentElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use document `write()` method, like this:

```
var iframeDoc = $('iframe')[0].contentDocument; // jQuery is just for the example of course
iframeDoc.write(data);
```

Where data is a full valid page source string, including DOCTYPE, HEAD, etc...

### -DEMO-

Comment: @Alvaro Just as a side note, if html string contains some external links using relative URL, you could have to set inside `head`section (usually) of iframe the `base` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Write does actually an "append". Isn't there a way to simulate a `.html` by overriding any possible content?

Comment: @Alvaro `iframeDoc.open(); iframeDoc.write(data);`