# javascript Add metacharset to iframe head

Tags: javascript, iframe, meta

Hi I have an iframe like this

```
<iframe id=iframeId">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I want to add a meta tag in head of iframe. I got inspired of this but nothing worked.
[append element in head of an iframe using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990165/append-element-in-head-of-an-iframe-using-jquery)
So I want this:

```
<iframe id=iframeId">
    <html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
    </iframe>
```

I tried to do

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.httpEquiv = "Content-type";
    meta.content = "text/html; charset=UTF-8" >

 $('head', window.frames['iframeId'].document).append(meta);
```

But I have an error in the console. document is null.

PS: I'm in IE

Comment: `id=iframeId"` to `id="iframeId"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors on your code, and you don't need jQuery for that.

HTML Code:

```
<iframe id="myIFrame">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Javascript code:

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "Content-type";
meta.content = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";

var doc = document.getElementById('myIFrame').contentWindow.document.head;
doc.append(meta);
```

I made a working example on JSFiddle, because stacksnippet does not allow me to use IFrames, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7s0vg8/1/

Comment: @LovePoke - 'not working for me' doesn't help anybody!